# Convert IEventBus to EventBus for Rule.addTarget() - Sending Event from EventBus to Event Bus in Same Account

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to setup a rule to send an Event from one Event Bus to another within the same account using the CDK.

The problem I'm having is the Rule() only accepts things that implement IRuleTarget.

Creating a new Event Bus returns the EventBus class that does implement IRuleTarget.
But looking up an EventBus returns IEventBus which doesn't implement IRuleTarget.

Is there a way I can lookup my Event Bus and apply it as a target to a Rule?

```
// Define EventBus1
const eventBus1 = new EventBus(this, 'eventBus1', {
  eventBusName: 'eventBus1Name',
});

// Look up my Event Bus in the other account, this method returns an IEventBus
const iEventBus2 = EventBus.fromEventBusArn(this, 'eventBus2', 'eventBus2Arn');

// My bad attempt to convert it, this didn't seem to work
const eventBus2 = EventBus.bind(iEventBus2);

// Create Rule to send event from eventBus1 to eventBus2
const eventBus1ToEventBus2Rule = new Rule(this, 'eventBus1ToEventBus2Rule', {
  eventBus: eventBus1,
  eventPattern: {
    'detailType': ['eventDetailType'],
  },
});

// Fails with in error I'll copy in below
eventBus1ToEventBus2Rule.addTarget(eventBus2);
```

> Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for
> "CfnRuleProps"   targets: element 0: supplied properties not correct
> for "TargetProperty"
> arn: required but missing.

This is using 1.115.0 versions of the aws-cdk.
Everything is being built through EventBridge.

Answer (score 0):

`fromEventBusArn` is on the `EventBus` class. `EventBus` extends (inherits) `BaseEventBus` which implements `IEventBus` and thus can be used anywhere an `IEventBus` is needed.  So, I think that you can simply cast the return value of `fromEventBusArn` to an `EventBus`.

Instead of this:

```js
const iEventBus2 = EventBus.fromEventBusArn(this, 'eventBus2', 'eventBus2Arn');
const eventBus2 = EventBus.bind(iEventBus2);
```

Do this:

```js
const eventBus = EventBus.fromEventBusArn(this, 'eventBus2', 'eventBus2Arn') as EventBus;
```

However, that resulting variable `eventBus` can't be passed to `eventBus1ToEventBus2Rule.addTarget()` as you're doing, because it failed with the following error, and I'm not really sure how it worked originally...

```js
Argument of type 'EventBus' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IRuleTarget'.
  Property 'bind' is missing in type 'EventBus' but required in type 'IRuleTarget'.
```

Comment: I'm guessing calling that .bind() tricked it somehow.
I feel like there must be a simple way to target an event bus with a rule. It's clearly available as an option in the console.

Comment: I had some luck getting a rule to creating doing new EventBus(eventBus2) where this EventBus is the one from @aws-cdk/aws-events-targets https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-events-targets.EventBus.html